# GeneXus Platform SDK installer not working for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, project-template, genexus

I'm trying to setup an environment to develop a Genexus extension for version 15.

After installing Visual Studio Express 2015 (based on Genexus wiki instructions) I'm installing [Genexus SDK Platform 15 Upgrade 3](https://www.genexus.com/developers/DownloadCenter?en,,,5282;platform%20sdk%2015;)

The SDK installer pop up an error "Can't find VStudio 2005 or 2008", and continue installation.

But Genexus projects templates are not available in VStudio 2015 after that.
It worked fine for VS2008.

I also try [this](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?27520,GX%20Project%20templates%20not%20included%20in%20Visual%20Studio,) GeneXus wiki suggestion but it doesn't work.
It is about manually installing this files inside VStudio folders.

```
GeneXus Package.ico
GeneXus Package.vsdir
GeneXus Package.vsz
GeneXus Pattern.ico
GeneXus Pattern.vsdir
GeneXus Pattern.vsz
```

Please, I need help to get the Visual Studio working with GeneXus platform SDK.