# Can't get GeneXus Extensions Development enviroment working (VS2015/2017)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, project-template, genexus

I'm trying to learn how GeneXus extensions works and trying to get a GeneXus extensions Development enviroment. I saw there are a [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208217/genexus-platform-sdk-installer-not-working-for-visual-studio-2015) about this question with the same problem I have.

It's marked as solved but there are something not explained or something like that because I can't get it working.
I tried with VS Community 2017 and VS Express 2015 Desktop.
I installed Genexus SDK from [enlace](https://www.genexus.com/developers/DownloadCenter?en,,,5282;platform%20sdk%2015;)
I downloaded and copied to the right place, the files mentioned in Valid Answer from the other thread, but still without see in any place where to create the GeneXus project in VS.

About files mentioned in the other thread and wiki as troubleshooting, I don't have it in any place in my HD.

```
GeneXus Package.ico
GeneXus Package.vsdir
GeneXus Package.vsz
GeneXus Pattern.ico
GeneXus Pattern.vsdir
GeneXus Pattern.vsz
```

Some idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Please reformulate your question in English.

Answer (score 1):

Giuseppe

After installing the SDK, you should find a "GeneXus Package" option among those at "New Project" Installed/Templates/Visual C#.

In other words, just use the "File / New / Project" menu, navigate to "Installed / Templates / Visual C#" and you should find a "Genexus Package" option.

[image: Visual Studio New Project dialog]

Hope that helps,

--
JLR

Comment: This is what I expected to see, but I didn't get that. I uninstalled all and I will try agian. Wich version I need? Express 2015 for Windows Desktop? Express 2015 for web? Express 2015 for Windows 10? Maybe community 2017?